# QuartzScheduler.NET - Adding new job definitions while scheduler is running

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Can anyone please say if quartz will allow you to add additional job types once the scheduler is up and running?

I reckon that our implementation of quarts will be an asp.net service using ram store.  It is likely that new jobs will be written over time and that we will want to add these jobs into the scheduler without having to shut the service down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as the classes related to the new job types make it into the classpath, and your class loader will discover them.   Quartz does nothing to "preload" or "prediscover" job classes - it just loads them as they're referenced.

Comment: Many thanks.  Actually, I'm using .NET rather than java, but understand it's more than likely that the same applies.

Comment: That's right, Quartz.NET is to a large degree just a transliteration of Quartz itself.